# Multiple jquery slideshows in same div (area)

Tags: jquery, slideshow, cycle, show-hide

I've got a head-scratcher of a problem, at least for me. I can not for the life of me figure out how to have a new slideshow play "on top" or "replace" another. It needs to be in the same div/space.

Please view the live page @ http://infin80.com/new/print-design/las-vegas-graphic-design.php

When clicking on the view button for each category, i'd like a different slideshow (set of photos) to play in that same space. Is it a show/hide script that I need? If at all possible, I'd like to maintain the "output" description function. Thank you all in advance.

This is the functioning cycle slideshow:

```
$('#rotate').cycle({ 
fx:     'fade', 
speed:  500, 
timeout: 4000, 
pause: 1,
next:   '#next2', 
prev:   '#prev2',
before:  onBefore, 
after:   onAfter 
});
function onBefore() { 
    $('#output').html('<h5>' + "CURRENT IMAGE (Scroll over to pause):" + '</h5>'); 
} 
function onAfter() { 
    $('#output').append('<h3>' + this.alt + '</h3>'); 
}
```